# FBX Loader Loading Issues

Tags: javascript, three.js, fbx

I'm a bit new to three.js, so I was trying out the FBXloader capabilities, but unfortunately it is not reliably loading all my models. Rather, some models it seems to have no problem with (untextured Mixamo downloads) but for others (textured Mixamo downloads mostly) it seems to have stopped altogether in the middle.

[ex: models that don't work](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9GQ-94q0FoKeVVUSnp4VHRrbGs?usp=sharing)

For all cases, the percentage calculation will not show. I don't think my onProgress() is even being used, and onError() certainly isn't.

I'm using FBXloader only, not FBXloader2. (I don't know where to find it, and I don't know if it will fix these issues, but maybe it doesn't hurt to try? It would be nice if you could point me in the general direction as to where to find it!)

EDIT: adding my loader code 
`

```
function loadFBX(paths) {
  var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader( manager );
  loader.load(paths[pathIndex]+" ", function( object ) {
    var scaler = 1;
    object.scale.set(scaler,scaler,scaler);
    object.position.x = 0;
    object.position.y = -.75;
    object.position.z = 0;

    if (object.animations.length>0) {
      object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
      mixers.push( object.mixer );
      var action = object.mixer.clipAction( object.animations[ 0 ] );
      action.play();
    }

    object.traverse(function(child) {
      if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh) {
        var helper = new THREE.SkeletonHelper( child.skeleton.bones[2] );
        helper.skeleton = child.skeleton;
        helper.material.linewidth = 10;
        scene.add( helper );
        helpers.push(helper);
        helper.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( helper );
        mixers.push( helper.mixer );
      }

    });
    scene.add( object );
  }, onProgress, onError );
}`
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Done! Also, I'd like to add: the load function doesn't even run with some models, it seems like...

Comment: Post the Models that aren't working. This isn't enough information to help you.